# How to call this javascript function from WKWebView Swift?

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, function, wkwebview

So I have this function on my site:

```js
function appQrHandlerSet(result) {
    jQuery(function() {
        jQuery('#readed_qr_url').val(result.url);
        jQuery(this).getLayerForm('#qr_handler_layer');
            });      
}
```

From the iOS app, I have to call this function and pass a JSON to it, how can I achieve that?
I've been trying to make it work for 3 days now, but I gave up because something is not working right.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your code, the parameter `result` should contain the property `url`. We suppose that the url contains the JSON data you want to pass.
Try the following 2 approaches:

```
// Approach 1:
func callJS() {
    let json = "{ url:\"An url with json?\"}"
    let scriptString = "let result=\(json); appQrHandlerSet(result);"
    webView?.evaluateJavaScript(scriptString, completionHandler: { (object, error) in

    })
}

// Approach 2:
func initWebViewWithJs() {
    let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    config.userContentController = WKUserContentController()

    let json = "{ url:\"An url with json?\"}"
    let scriptString = "let result=\(json); appQrHandlerSet(result);"
    let script = WKUserScript(source: scriptString, injectionTime: WKUserScriptInjectionTime.atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: true)
    config.userContentController.addUserScript(script)

    webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 400), configuration: config)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the first approach solved all my problems!